# process cell selection in Excel in reverse order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a process that pastes data into spreadsheet, at random locations.
Since I can never be sure where the data will be pasted before hand, I thought I could process the selection area.

This code shows the data from top to bottom.
I want to do this in the reverse order though

```
Debug.Print "Selected Range : " & Selection.Areas(1).Address(False, False)
For Each R In Selection.Areas(1)
    Debug.Print R.Address(False, False)
Next
```

Most of the solutions I've found deal with reversing an array and passing the the results to a target.
I just want to process the selection from the last cell to the first cell.
Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
Sub loopBack()
    Dim c As Long, area As Range
    Set area = Selection.Areas(1)
    Debug.Print "Selected Range : " & area.Address(False, False)
    For c = area.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print area.Cells(c).Address(False, False)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: "area.cells.count" was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks so much for the code. it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The code only loop through the first area of Selection in reverse order.

```vb
Sub demo1()
    Dim rRow As Range, rSel As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Set rSel = Selection.Areas(1)
    Debug.Print "Selected Range : " & rSel.Address(False, False)
    For i = rSel.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set rRow = rSel.Rows(i)
        For j = rRow.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print rRow.Cells(j).Address(False, False)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub demo2()
    Dim rSel As Range, i As Long
    Set rSel = Selection.Areas(1)
    Debug.Print "Selected Range : " & rSel.Address(False, False)
    For i = rSel.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print rSel.Cells(i).Address(False, False)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. both pieces of code work nicely. selection.cells.count was the bit missing from my understanding.